# javascript using variables for object keys and values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
 pub.call_response = function() {
            return {
                units: [
                    {
                        test_attributes: {

                        }

                    }
                ]
            };
        };
```

I have a set of variables that I need to use for the keys/values in `test_attributes` as follows:

```
var key1 = something;
var key2 = something;
var value1 = something;
var value2 = something;

pub.call_response = function() {
                return {
                    units: [
                        {
                            test_attributes: {
                               key1: value1,
                               key2: value2
                            }

                        }
                    ]
                };
            };
```

Obviously, this does not work. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do something like this? Using jQuery is acceptable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should do

```
var key1 = something;
var key2 = something;
var value1 = something;
var value2 = something;

var attributes = {};

attributes[key1] = value1;
```

Answer (score 1):

To reference the property `prop` on the object `obj` (i.e. `prop.obj`) you can also use the square brackets `[]`

So, the following are equivalent:

```
var x = prop.obj;

var key = "obj";
var t = prop[key];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var key1 = something;
var key2 = something;
var value1 = something;
var value2 = something;

pub.call_response = function() {
    var item = {
        test_attributes: {}
    };
    item.test_attributes[key1] = value1;
    item.test_attributes[key2] = value2;

    var obj = {
        units: [item]
    };

    return obj;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var key1 = something;
var key2 = something;
var value1 = something;
var value2 = something;

pub.call_response = function() {
    var u    = {};
    u[key1]  = value1;
    u[key2]  = value2;

    return {
         units: [{
             test_attributes : u
         }]
    };
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var obj = {};
obj[key1] = value1;
obj[key2] = value2;

return {
    units: [ { test_attributes: obj } ]
};
```